# Fixed Background in a Matter.js world

Tags: matter.js

I am looking for a way to set a background fixed to the world. In my case, `Render.lookAt` targets a moving body and I need to display a fiexd grid behind it to enhance the body’s movements. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create a body inside the world with a background sprite.

You can do this like so:

```
var gridBackground = Bodies.rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1, {
    isStatic: true,
    isSensor: true,
    render: {
        sprite: {
            texture: "Path/To/Image.png",
            xScale: neededScale,
            yScale: neededScale
        }
    }
});
World.add(world, gridBackground);
```

If your world is infinite, you can also use the grid as a `background-image` on the body/canvas in css and move it in the opposite direction the player is moving:

```
Matter.Events.on(engine, "beforeupdate", function() {
    var x = player.position.x * -1;
    var y = player.position.y * -1;
    Matter.Render.lookAt(render, {
        min: {y:y-FoV/2, x:x-FoV/2},
        max: {y:y+FoV/2, x:x+FoV/2},
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if my world is not finite?